# How to run NDK implemented Android code with Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-studio

I tried importing ndk implemented android code into Android studio , it got imported but now it is showing error in the path "/lib/include/myFile.h" . Even if that file is there, android studio not picking it. Even tried adding path to Classpath in properties file. Anyone having idea?

Comment: Can you post your "build.gradle" file and the directory structure with files?  Thanks.

Comment: http://ph0b.com/android-studio-gradle-and-ndk-integration/  review it.